# Meaning of 'lift' in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a quote about [Bracken fronds](https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=Bracken%20fronds&hl=ko&sxsrf=ALeKk02eEX44WQiwuulkK78pA3nnsmIHXg:1603931396625&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_-Y6JxtjsAhUSGaYKHcIoB7YQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1205&bih=564):

> "Bracken fronds **have** full body and **great lift**"

"Lift" is normally a verb - what does it mean in this context when it appears to be a noun? The only nouns listed in Collins dictionary are an elevator or a boost to mood or confidence.

Comment: You've linked to a set of pictures, not to a context for "great lift".

Comment: "Lift", in this sense, might be a horticultural term, used by florists or botanists. At a guess, it might mean the ferns don't droop. Of course, "lift" can mean getting a ride, an elevator, theft, a device to raise shoes, or raising one's spirits, but those won't do here.

Comment: Please tell us the source of the quote.

Comment: I am more curious about "have ull body", I have never heard of any plant as being "full bodied". I would have to guess its meaning. Is this sentence a translation by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lift" is a verb which means to *raise* something. However, it is also used in some contexts as a *noun* for the property or quality of having been raised.

This example is from an [article](https://hair.allwomenstalk.com/smart-tips-for-creating-volume-on-the-crown/) about hair:

> Creating volume at the crown gives you all the lift, bounce, and body you need.

Hair that has been styled to make it lift up is said to *have lift*.

In your example, plants are described as having "lift" if their foliage is raised rather than drooping.